# TypeError: scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trendline_options' (Plotly, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, graph, plotly, trendline

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trendline_options'
```

When trying to adjust the smoothing of the lowess tendline using plotly express.

Here is my code for the graph:

```
fig = px.scatter(dfg, x="Yr_Mnth", y="Episode_Count", color = "Target",
                        labels={"Episode_Count": tally + " per Shift",
                                "Target":"Target",
                                "Yr_Mnth": "Date" },
                        trendline='lowess',trendline_options= dict(frac=0.1), title="Aggregate Behavior Data: " + patient + " - " + today)
        fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,)
        fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_white',hovermode="x unified")
```

Dataset (dfg):

```
Yr_Mnth                         Target              Episode_Count
2020-08-01                     Aggression           0.09
2020-08-01                      Elopement           0.00
2020-08-01                    Self-injury           0.97
2020-09-01                     Aggression           0.65
2020-09-01                      Elopement           0.00
2020-09-01                    Self-injury           1.58
2020-10-01                     Aggression           0.24
2020-10-01                      Elopement           0.00
2020-10-01                    Self-injury           0.75
2020-11-01                     Aggression           0.03
2020-11-01                      Elopement           0.01
2020-11-01                    Self-injury           0.89
2020-12-01                     Aggression           0.14
2020-12-01                      Elopement           0.00
2020-12-01                    Self-injury           0.94
2021-01-01                     Aggression           0.05
2021-01-01                      Elopement           0.00
2021-01-01                    Self-injury           0.30
2021-02-01                    Self-injury           0.42
2021-02-01                      Elopement           0.03
2021-02-01                     Aggression           0.16
2021-03-01                      Elopement           0.00
2021-03-01                    Self-injury           0.68
2021-03-01                     Aggression           0.20
2021-04-01                     Aggression           0.10
2021-04-01                      Elopement           0.03
2021-04-01                    Self-injury           0.33
2021-05-01                      Elopement           0.20
2021-05-01                     Aggression           0.21
2021-05-01                    Self-injury           1.63
2021-06-01                    Self-injury           0.90
2021-06-01                     Aggression           0.29
2021-06-01                      Elopement           0.14
```

I find this strange as I'm directly following the documentation - https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/

Is this a known issue? I can't find any examples with a google search...

Comment: [OLS Parameters](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#ols-parameters) are "new in v5.2". This code does not raise this error in any supported version currently (5.2.0 or 5.2.1)

Comment: You're right, was totally a version thing... great spot! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Henry helpfully pointed out this was just a version problem, easily addressed by updating plotly using:

```
pip install plotly==5.2.1
```